# Angular2 dynamic img src

Tags: angular

I have the following code:

```
<a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active" #rla="routerLinkActive">
          <img src="/assets/navigation/dashboard-icon-active.svg" />
        <template [ngIf]="!isSmallSidebar">
          Dashboard
        </template>
      </a>
```

Running my app I see the image displayed correctly. However I want the image to change if the current route is active. So I did:

```
<a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active" #rla="routerLinkActive">
        <!-- <img
          id="re-nav-dashboard-img"
          src={{ rla.isActive ? './assets/navigation/dashboard-icon-active.svg' : './assets/navigation/dashboard-icon.svg' }} /> -->
        <template [ngIf]="!isSmallSidebar">
          Dashboard
        </template>
      </a>
```

This on the other hand results in:
[image]

What am I doing wrong or is this a bug ?

Answer (score 13):

You should use Angular 2 bindings differently.

Your `<img>` tag should be:

```
<img id="re-nav-dashboard-img" [src]="rla.isActive ? './assets/navigation/dashboard-icon-active.svg' : './assets/navigation/dashboard-icon.svg'" />
```

Notice the square brackets around the `src` attribute, and the template expression between the quotes.

Some reading about property bindings: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding

Comment: If the bound value is a string, they are equivalent.

Comment: what is the difference with my approach ?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I wasn't aware but after reading https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#interpolation I must agree :)

Comment: I like when people agree with me :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve it by doing a unary 'IF' in nested form

```
    <td class="cent">
         <img  [src]="OrdersFund?.status=='P' ? 'assets/P.png' : OrdersFund?.status=='E' ? 'assets/E.png' : 'assets/C.png'" /> 
    </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. This is the correct way.

```
<img id="re-nav-dashboard-img" src="{{rla.isActive ? './assets/navigation/dashboard-icon-active.svg' : './assets/navigation/dashboard-icon.svg'}}" />
```

I was using `src={{}}` instead of `src="{{}}"`.

Answer (score 1):

I came across with same problem. My solution is a bit tricky to change src of image. 
In html:

```
<div id="imageDiv"></div>
```

In angular:

```
document.getElementById('imageDiv').innerHTML = '<img src="' + YourPhotoURLOrBase64String + '"/>';
```